# jquery plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin (from a other code I have), but I just can't get the options part to work D:

Plugin (so far):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.scBox = function(options){
        var $opts = $.extend($.fn.scBox.defaults, options);

        $.fn.scBox.defaults = {
            start: 40,
            //i: fn.scBox.defaults.start,
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            min: 0,
            step: 10,
            fontSize: 15,
            textColor: "#fff",
            bgColor: "#000",
            slideColor: "#ff0000"
        }

        console.log($.fn.scBox.defaults);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

When I try to call it by `$.scBox();`, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'scBox'` I just want it to log the options I gave to it D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery plugins are called on jQuery objects.  You aren't supposed to call them directly.  You're supposed to call it on a jQuery object.

```
$('#myElement').scBox();
```

Also, you're calling `$.extend` on `$.fn.scBox.defaults` *before* you declare it.

```
    $.fn.scBox.defaults = {
        start: 40,
        //i: fn.scBox.defaults.start,
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        min: 0,
        step: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        textColor: "#fff",
        bgColor: "#000",
        slideColor: "#ff0000"
    }

    var $opts = $.extend($.fn.scBox.defaults, options);
```

NOTE: `$.extend` modifies the object passed as the 1st parameter (it also returns it).  So, you don't need the `var $opts =`:

```
$.extend($.fn.scBox.defaults, options);
console.log($.fn.scBox.defaults);
```

Or, you can do:

```
var $opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.scBox.defaults, options);
console.log($opts);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nfDTh/

Answer (score 2):

Call `$.fn.scBox()`, not `$.scBox()`. This is demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT8cn/1/), whose code is pasted below.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.scBox = function(options){
        $.fn.scBox.defaults = {
            start: 40,
            //i: fn.scBox.defaults.start,
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            min: 0,
            step: 10,
            fontSize: 15,
            textColor: "#fff",
            bgColor: "#000",
            slideColor: "#ff0000"
        }
        var $opts = $.extend($.fn.scBox.defaults, options);
        console.log($opts);
    }
    $.fn.scBox();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.paginator = function(options){

           var defaults = {
                items_per_page              :   10,
                num_page_links_to_display   :   4,
                start_page                  :   1,
                total_items                 :   20,
                label_first                 :    'First',
                label_prev                  :   'Prev',
                label_next                  :   'Next',
                label_last                  :   'Last',
                show_first_last             :   true,
                onChange                    :   function(){return false;}
            };
            var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.paginator.defaults, options);

            return this.each(function(){
              //Code in here
            });
};
```

This is a some part of a working plugin I've made. I hope It helps! Notice that **$.extend**  is called after declaring de **defaults var**